# signal EOF of stdin when in mac OS X terminal with ctrl+D doesn't work

Tags: haskell, io, osx-elcapitan

I am on a mac OS X EL Captain and try to figure out how to  signal  EOF , however ctrl + D  doesn't work. I have confirmed with the terminal using `stty all`  that eof = ^D.

With the following code in Haskell

```
Module Input where

import Data.List
import Data.Char
import System.IO (isEOF)


main =
   interact (concat . sort . lines)
```

The expression will never give me any stdout -  I have tried ctrl+d , but nothing happens. Why is this?

*I run this program in GHCI*

Comment: Are you trying to run it in ghci?  It works for me via  `runhaskell program.hs`.  Update: under OSX 10.10.5, that is.

Answer (score 2):

(Note: Question about running the program in GHCI.)

According to [this TRAC issue](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1268) from 9 years ago it is not considered a bug.

You can `hSetBuffer stdin LineBuffering` and Control-D will be recognized, but GHCI will also raise a "handle is closed" error when it comes back to the REPL prompt and the session will terminate:

```
$ ghci  ./control-d.hs
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Input            ( control-d.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Input.
*Input> import System.IO
*Input System.IO>  hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
*Input System.IO> :main
jhskdfjhdf
jhskdfjhdf<stdin>: hGetBuffering: illegal operation (handle is closed)
$
```